# Get JSON from Web Service Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I get this error when I click the button in HTML to use my JavaScript.

```
myapp.azurewebsites.net/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

JS:

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    console.log("ajaxFunction()");
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                alert("Broken");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {

            var form = document.getElementById("myform");
            var titleParagraph = document.getElementById("home_title");
            titleParagraph.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;

            form.style.display = "none";

        }
    } 

    var value1 = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("field2").value;
    var url = "https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/users/" + value1 + "/" + value2;
    console.log(url);

    // Call sign in web service

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    console.log("RESPONSE:");
    console.log(jsonResponse);
}
```

This JSON is what I get when I go to https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/users/value1/value2

```
[{"ID":1,"UserName":"username","FirstName":"first","LastName":"last","email":"example@example.com"}]
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `ajaxRequest.responseText`?

Comment: @JordanRunning see my update.

Comment: try checking for `ajaxRequest.responseText` in the readystatechange handler you set up (inside `readyState == 4 && status == 200` block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, false);
```

Third parameter says if the request is asynchronous or not. So by looking at your code it should be synchronous.

Comment: When I change that, I get  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Use setRequestHeader() to add that into it